# Adding a token to the network

Tags: tokens

If you add the contract as a pre sale, that will generate the tokens on the network and I can still add the rest of the smart contract before I finalize it. Is this correct?

We want to start issuing the tokens, but the full contract is not done yet.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you write the token contract (see the possible duplicate).

But it is not recommend to start issuing tokens when the full contract is not done, for a few reasons:

1. what assurances do your purchasers have that you will not dilute them (beyond what you promise them)?  The power of using a smart contract is that people can see that the contract does not have any special cases for you or anyone else: a promise is not as strong as a contract enforced on a public blockchain.
2. writing an upgradeable contract is more complicated